# DevExpress MemoEdit layout issue

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0, devexpress

I want to show some text inside the MemoEdit in two columns. The parse of the text works correctly because when I see the parsed text inside Notepad or when I debug it inside Visual Studio it shows it in two columns, so the text is formatted exactly in the way I need it. The problem is that when it is shown inside the MemoEdit, it doesn't keep the format (I think this is because it uses a different font for the text, not a fixed size width font, because white spaces are smaller then normal characters). I changed the font to some fixed size width font and is showing it correctly, but the problem is that I need to have the same font like the application uses. Is there any property on MemoEdit that can help me achive the behavior I want without changing the font?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can use the MemoEdit control as an in-place editor to show multiple 
lines of text. Try one of the following variants:
1)set the View's RowAutoHeight property to true
2)specify the height of rows via the RowHeight property

Comment: Could you please provide me some code sample? I can't find the properties you mentioned.

Comment: The properties I mentioned are given in example below by another User. I hope it helps you.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can activate the **RowAutoHeight** option of the **GridView.OptionsView** property in GUI and you can set it pragmatically as below:

```
gridView1.OptionsView.RowAutoHeight = true;
```

You can also use **CalcRowHeight** event handler to tweak the height of the gridview rows. check the reference links.

Reference these DevExpress fourm thread -
[Auto-height of grid rows and text WordWrap](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/KB/p/a8.aspx)
[GridControl row height (cell height)](http://devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/CQ24983.aspx)
[Changing row height at runtime](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q135099.aspx)

Comment: I gave the properties name. And you elaborated it. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I don't have any grid, it's a standalone MemoEdit control.